# Users App-Scoped user id in Facebook is the same between apps

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

in the new V2 Facebook API Graph call i got this new "id" that has to be different for each apps like stated on here [app-scoped id](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids) . I have 3 different ios apps that share the same Facebook App ID, but the results are always the same between all of them. I have set all the bundle id, urlsuffix between each apps and they are different. Is it because they share the same Facebook App ID?

note: I am sure that I have called the v2 graph, because the results showed https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

If your three iOS apps share the same Facebook App ID, then it's just natural that the App-scoped User IDs are the same!

I don't really understand why you chose to use all three with the same FB App, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: the FB app name called Hi-City, and the apps that use this App Id are Hi-Bali, Hi-Bandung etc. since on the FB dashboard they provide different bundle id and url suffix to, so I thought each of the app will produce different scope id.

Comment: No. One FB app = same App-scoped User IDs

Comment: Thanks @tobi I just have to create FB app for all of them :)